# Composer PHP Cannot install illuminate/database

Tags: php, composer-php

I am getting the below errors when trying to run:
composer require illuminate/database

I am new to composer so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

```
    Problem 1
        - php-xpdf/php-xpdf is locked to version 0.2.3 and an update of this package was not requested.
        - illuminate/database[v9.25.0, ..., v9.25.1] require symfony/console ^6.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v6.0.0, ..., v6.1.3].
        - symfony/console[v6.0.0, ..., v6.1.3] conflict with symfony/process <5.4.
        - alchemy/binary-driver 1.6.0 requires symfony/process ^2.0|^3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v3.4.47].   
        - php-xpdf/php-xpdf 0.2.3 requires alchemy/binary-driver ~1.5 -> satisfiable by alchemy/binary-driver[1.6.0].  
        - Root composer.json requires illuminate/database ^9.25 -> satisfiable by illuminate/database[v9.25.0, v9.25.1].

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require illuminate/database:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require illuminate/database:^2.1" if you know which you need.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a pretty old version of `php-xpdf/php-xpdf` (v0.2.3 which was released in July 2016!) that transitively requires a Symfony component in v2 or v3. Even the latest version of that package (released in 2018, so also horribly outdated!) makes use of another package that requires Symfony v2 or v3.

Check for replacements of `php-xpdf/php-xpdf` that are better maintained

Answer (score 1):

as @Nico Haase mentioned,
The only work-around was to replace php-xpdf/php-xpdf with something that would allow the upgrading of the required symfony component. The replacement I used was:
spatie/pdf-to-text